# How to replace the second matched word in every line?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a txt file containing about 10000 lines. In every line, I have a specific character (%20) that repeats two times. I need to replace the second occurrence with another word and keep the first one. Is there any Notepad++ Regular Expression for that?

Here is my text:

```
My name is %20John. my friend's name is %20john too.
My name is %20paul. my friend's name is %20paul too.
.
.
```

I need it to be like this:

```
My name is %20John. my friend's name is john too.    
My name is %20paul. my friend's name is paul too.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use something like this:

```
^(.+?%20.+?)%20
```

..and replace with:

```
\1
```

..which will remove the second occurrence of `%20`. If you want to replace it with something else (e.g., `SomeWord`), you may use `\1SomeWord` in the "Replace With" field.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHkr8M/1)**.

Comment: Thanks. It worked very well, but there was something I forgot to mention. The number of (%20)s varies in each line and I have even 10 of them in some lines, and therefore this Regex does not work in those lines. There is some constant part in all lines and it is (dl=0">). I need to remove all the (%20) after this constant and replace it with space. All (%20) before this constant should not be removed. Can you help me with that? example: %20my %name %is %john dl=0"> %20my %name %is %john should change to: %20my %name %is %john dl=0"> my name is john

Comment: @Sanila This sounds like a different question so, I would say it's probably a good time to [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will do the job as expected ...

Find what: `(.*?\K%){2}\d+`
Replace with: `nothing`